# Reusing one opened TCP connection between TCP client and TCP server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

There is third party service that expose TCP server to which my node server(TCP client) should establish TCP connection using `tls` node module.
Being TCP client, node server is also HTTP server at same time, that should act something like proxy between customers coming from web browser and third party TCP server. So common use case would be that browser will send HTTP request to node server from where node server will communicate with TCP server via TCP sockets to gather/construct response and to send it back to browser.

Current solution that i had is that **per each customer/each HTTP request** coming from web browser **new separated TCP connection will be established** with TCP server. This solution proved to be bad, wasting time to do SSL handshake every time and TCP server does not allow more than 50 concurrent connections coming from single client. So with this solution it is not possible to have more than 50 customers communicate with node server at once.

What would be something like standard approach to do this thing with `tls` module in node?

What i'm up to is having one single TCP connection that will be something like always active and that connection will be established in the time when node app will start and what is most important this connection should be reused for **many** HTTP request coming from web browser.

[image]

First concern that i have is how to construct different HTTP responses based on data that is coming from TCP server via TCP raw socket. The good thing is that i can send something like `unique token` via headers to TCP server when describing which action should be taken on TCP server side.

```
socket.write(JSON.stringify({
  header: {uniqueToken: 032424242, type: 'create something bla bla'},
  data: {...}
}))
```

Having unique token TCP server side **guarantee** that JSON when combined from different chunks coming over TCP socket and parsed will have this `uniqueToken` which means im able to map this JSON to HTTP request and to return HTTP response.

**My question is does in general TCP protocol guarantee that in this case different successive chunks will belong to the same response that needs to created when those chunks are combined and parsed (when `'\n\n'` occur)**
In another words is there any guarantee that chunks will not be mixed.
(Im aware that it can happen that chunk that contains `'\n\n'` can belong to two different responses but i will be able to handle that)

If that is not possible than i don't see a way in which first solution (having one connection for one response that needs to be created) can be improved. Only way would be to introduce some connection pooling concept which as far as i know `tls` module does not provide in any way out of the box.

**EDIT based on comments bellow, short version of question:**
Lets say that TCP server needs 2 seconds to send all chunks when it receives command `create something bla bla`
If TCP client send command `create something bla bla` and immediately after 1 millisecond it send second `create something bla bla`, is there any chance that could happen that TCP server will write chunk related to second command before it writes **all** chunks related to first command.

Comment: TCP is a reliable streaming protocol, i.e. the order of the data is preserved, no data are lost and no data are duplicated. Of course, if multiple senders write at the "same" time (i.e. threads or similar) to the TCP connection then the writes might not be in the order you like (or even partial only) and thus will the reads also not as you like because there order is preserved.

Comment: So in order to be sure that this would work like i described, i need to be sure that sender will not issue two successive writes that not belongs to same response that needs to be constructed? So it is like i need the guarantee from them?

Comment: @Srle, I think one could assume that one message is sent as a bulk and doesn't get framented *(even if the connection flushes the output buffer and starts sending while you're still writing)*. I don't think you can assume that order is preserved. In other words, that the order of responses is the same as the order of writes. I'd use some ID or (message-)header, to identify wich response belongs to wich write.

Comment: If you associate a TCP connection with a single HTTP client then it will probably work this way since HTTP/1.x does not interleave requests (HTTP/2 is different). But if you want to use the same TCP connections for multiple clients at the same time you don't have this guarantee anymore. Also note that TCP is a stream protocol, i.e. you have to define a protocol (or use an existing one like HTTP) so that the third party server knows where your request ends and you know where the response ends.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i have solution in which single HTTP client is associated with one single TCP connection, but solution proved to be bad and it is not scalable. Their side only allows 50 concurrent TCP connections at once, so imagine 1000 customers at site at once.

@Thomas what do you mean by `one could assume that one message is sent as a bulk and doesn't get framented `. And about `ID`, that means that every chunk/write from their side should carry this ID which they are not providing.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich but in general, should any TCP server write (with threads or not) to open TCP connection chunks that belongs to different issued command by TCP client. (When previous command didn't finished) That should not be the case because even in that case if i have one TCP connection per one customer i would receive invalid data, because i would read in same order as they write, right?

Comment: @Srle: I'm not really understanding your setup (many parties involved, some can be both client and server and it is not clear what you mean in each case). But in general: either you serialize the communication so that only one request/response is done and only after that is finished the next comes. Look at HTTP/1.x for this case. Or you allow interleaving data belonging to multiple request/response in which case each "segment" must have some identifier so that the segments for the same id can be reassembled. Look at HTTP/2 for this case. And, TCP is a stream and has no "message" boundaries.

Comment: @Srle, i mean that messages from multiple threads won't interleave, the integrity of the messages would be ensured, even if multiple threads try to write at the "same time"

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, @ Srle, I think we have to clarify this a bit. What protocol are we talking about? HTTP or Socket? And Srle, you've indicated that you have no control whatsoever over the responding Server, so how do you want to change the way of communication? What are the possibilities/limitations?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich mainly we are speaking about Socket, not HTTP. HTTP is just another part of this story. I believe question can be rephrased as, is there any chance that can happen that TCP server will issue chunk that not belongs to same command that TCP server received from TCP client. So, if TCP client send command `create something bla bla` and TCP server needs 2 seconds to send all chunks for that, after 1 millisecond TCP client send new message, there is no way that TCP server will write chunk related to new command after it writes all chunks related to first command (2 seconds in total)?

Comment: I think @Thomas is saying the same like my previous comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... is there any chance that could happen that TCP server will write chunk related to second command before it writes all chunks related to first command.

If I understand your question correctly you are asking if a `write("AB")` followed by a `write("CD")` on the same socket at the server side could result that the clients reads `ACDB` from the server.

This is not the case if both writes are successful and have actually written all the data to the underlying socket buffer. But, since TCP is a stream protocol with no implicit message boundary the read on the client side could be something like `ABCD` or `AB` followed by `CD` or `A` followed by `BC` followed by `D` etc. Thus to distinguish between the messages from the server you have to add some application level message detection, like an end of message marker, a size prefix or similar.

Also, I restricted the previous statement to *both writes are successful and have actually written all the data to the underlying socket buffer*. This is not necessarily the case. For example you might functions which do a buffered write like (in C) fwrite instead of write. In this case you usually don't control which parts of the buffer are written at which time so it might be that `fwrite("AB")` would result in "A" written to the socket while "B" kept in the buffer. If you then have another buffered writer which use the same underlying file descriptor (i.e socket) but not the same buffer then you could actually end up with something like `ACDB` send to the underlying socket and thus to the client.

This case could even happen if the unbuffered write with not fully successful, i.e. if a `write("AB")` has only written "A" and signals through the return value that "B" needs to be written later. If you have then a multi-threaded application with insufficient synchronization between threads you could end up with a case that the first threads sends "A" to the socket in the incomplete attempt to write "AB", followed by another thread sending "CD" successfully and then the first thread again completing the send by writing "B". In this case you also end up with "ACDB" on the socket.

In summary: the TCP layer guarantees that the send order is the same as the received order but the user space (i.e. application) needs to make sure that it really sends the data in the right order to the socket. Also, TCP has no message boundary so the distinction of messages inside the TCP stream need to be implemented inside the application by using message boundaries, length prefix, fixed message size or similar.